# Create a hierarchical multi-dimensional and assocative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, hierarchical-data, dynamic-arrays

I need to create a huge multi-dimensional and associative array from a "flat" array, to make it json-compliant:

```
$data = array (
    'Europe',
    'West',
    'Germany',
    'France',
    'Switzerland',
    'East',
    'Czech Republic',
    'Slovakia',
    'Poland')
```

for each entity I am able to say whether if it is consolidated (Europe, West and East), or basis elements (i.e. without children)

What I would like to achieve is the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [entity] => Europe
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [entity] => West
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [entity] => France
                                                )
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [entity] => Germany
                                                )
                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [entity] => Switzerland
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [entity] => East
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [entity] => Czech Republic
                                                )
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [entity] => Slovakia
                                                )
                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [entity] => Poland
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I already tried to write a recursive function for that:

```
function ListArray($top_elt)
{
    $myarray=array();   
    $myarray[0]['entity']=$top_elt;
        // foreach element of the list
        foreach($children as $child) 
        {
                //element is consolidated : call the recursive function to list the children
                // this is the function that returns whether the element is consolidated or not
                if(palo_etype($connect,'Demo','Regions',$child)=='consolidated')
                {
            $myarray[0]['children'][]['entity']=$child;
            ListArray($child);
        }
                else //basis element
                {
            $myarray[0]['children'][]['entity']=$child;
                }
        }        
        return $myarray;
}
```

but it only returns Europe, West and East...

do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance for your support !

Cheers,
laloune

Comment: Have you considering converting this multi dimensional array in an array of objects?

Comment: Hi Vlad, what do you mean with "an array of objects" ? Do you mean "an array of array of array ... of array^n" ? I try actually to append dynamically the following elements (for instance ['children'][] to the current array. But I don't have any idea for that :-(

Comment: I'm very desesperated... I have the impression that what I try to achieve is complete impossible. Is it really ?

Comment: No, I mean using object oriented programming (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). Can you tell us the format of starting data? (the first `$data` array is not enough to create the multi dimensional array)

Comment: Hi Vlad,

actually the format of the $data array can be modified accordingly. For instance I can generate such an array:

    array(
    [0]=>array(
    name=>Europe, children=>array(
    [0]=>West,
    [1]=>East
    )
    ),
    [1]=>array(
    name=>West,children=>array(
    [0]=>array(name=>Germany,children=>),
    [1]=>array(name=>France,children=>),
    [2]=>array(name=>Switzerland,children=>)
    )

when children is empty, that would mean that it is  base element

do you think that would help ?

Thanks for your support !
laloune